# Searching strings from one file in another file and retrieving the line

Tags: python

I have two files named A and B
A file looks like this:

```
1_A  
2_B  
3_C  
4_D  
5_E
```

B file looks like this:

```
C  
D
```

so wrote a small script using file B to search for the corresponding line that contain "C" and "D
here is my code:

```
import re  
f = open("fileA", "r")  
t = open("fileB", "r")  
for line1 in f:  
    for line2 in t:  
        if line2 in line1:  
            print(line1)
```

But the result was blank, does anyone have any ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: I'd like the results be "3_C, 4_D"

Comment: Print line1 and line2 before the if condition and see why they differ.

Comment: Please format your code..

Comment: You `import re` but never use it. It's unnecessary here.

Answer (score 1):

After the first iteration, the file pointer in file B is at end of file, and you can't read anything more from it.

Trivial solutions involve rewinding file B or equivalently opening it inside the loop and closing it after each iteration. The I/O overhead is somewhat prohibitive, though.

On the other hand, reading both files into memory so you can compare them is not very scalable, especially if the files are big.

The usual compromise is to read the smaller file into memory, then processing one line at a time from the bigger file.

```
with open("fileB", "r") as t:
    terms = [x.rstrip('\n') for x in t]
with open("fileA", "r") as f: 
    for line in f:
        if any([term in line for term in terms]):
            print(line)
```

If the files are too big for this, you might want to split file B into smaller chunks and do multiple passes, or, if at least one of the files is fairly static, look at using a database.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this with `readlines`,

```
a_lines = open('FileA.txt', 'r').readlines()
b_lines = open('FileB.txt', 'r').readlines()

[a_line.strip() for b_line in b_lines for a_line in a_lines if b_line in a_line]
# Returns ['3_C', '4_D']
```

Comment: This requires the match to occur at the end of line. `readlines()` includes the terminating newline at the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

use `readlines()` after opening files:

```
import re
f = open("FileA", "r").readlines()
t = open("FileB", "r").readlines()
for line1 in f:
    for line2 in t:
        if line2 in line1:
            print(line1)
```

Comment: I tried  aloop over a file without using readlines and just printed, and it did print out my file. What's the major difference? I'm guessing it loops over bytes when you iterate a file, and not the lines?

Comment: readlines() returns a list() that you can iterate in a nested loop, open() returns file that you can iterate only once. when it reaches the end of the file, there is no coming back

Answer (score -1):

You can open second file and save the output and then open file file and just check if any item[2] from second file is in first list :

```
list_=[]

with open('second','r') as f:

    for line in f:
        list_.append(line.split()[0])


final_list=[]
with open('first','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[2] in list_:
            final_list.append(line.split()[0])

print(final_list)
```

output:

```
['3_C', '4_D']
```

Answer (score -2):

To be in line with your code, you can try the following:

```
f = open("fileA", "r")
t = open("fileB", "r")

for line1 in f:
    for line2 in t:
        if line2 in line1:
            print(line1)
    t.seek(0) # reset the file pointer after going through the entire file
```

Comment: Please leave the reason for the down vote. The code works fine for me and yields the desired output.

Comment: Seeking back and reading file B again for each line in file A is extremely inefficient, to the point where this is unusable in many real-life scenarios. Not my downvote, though.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @triplee.